# Add camera to existing connection between two user

Tags: jquery, html, webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

I am facing this error when i add camera to existing connection, here is code by which i am connecting or adding the additional camera to the connection from first user to second user

```
 if (connection.mediaConstraints.video.optional.length && connection.attachStreams.length)
 { 
     connection.mediaConstraints.video.optional[0].sourceId = videoSourceId;
     var stream = event.stream;
     connection.removeStream({ audio: true });
     connection.addStream({ audio: true, video: true });
     videoId = this.id; 
  }
```

and this error occurs when i am trying this
error:
[image]

and by searching for this error i have tried every things but didn't get any solution if any one can give my solution.

Comment: Why are you adding mediaConstraints again to `addStream` ? You can add only `stream` to `addStream`

Comment: ya i agree with you but in it javascript it uses `mediaConstraints` for recognizing the video stream and audio stream so i tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
connection.mediaConstraints.video = {
    mandatory: {}, // keep this empty or use valid parameters
    optional: [{ // reset or override optional array
        sourceId: 'video-source-id'
    }]
};

if (DetectRTC.browser.name === 'Firefox') {
    connection.mediaConstraints.video = {
        deviceId: 'video-source-id' // Firefox requires "deviceId"
    };
}

connection.addStream({
    video: true
});
```

#### Points:

1. Make sure that there is ONLY_ONE `sourceId` in the `optional` array.

   That's why always override/reset `optional` array.
2. Make sure that `mandatory` constraints has empty or valid parameters.

Comment: why we give directly video a deviceId in FireFox option can you explain me this

Comment: Please check this: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/deviceId](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/deviceId)